# Entity Framework Command Hyphenation Makes no Sense?

Tags: entity-framework

Consider the following command:

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration: "SomeMigrationName"
```

Why is is `Update-Database` hyphenated one way and `-TargetMigration` another?

Another example is `Get-Migrations` vs `-ConfigurationTypeName`

Is it general commands vs setting it up to specify a file? Please let me know if this was the logic behind what seems like counter-intuitive hyphenation.

Edit: BUT `Add-Migration` is both a command and followed by a specification, though a new one is being created. Confusing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Update-Database
```

is the command

```
-TargetMigration
```

Is a named parameter

These are PowerShell commands.

The hyphens represent two different things here.

1) The hyphen in `Update-Database` is just to separate the words Update and Database. Pretty standard for PowerShell commands

2) The hyphen at the beginning of `-TargetMigration` is to indicate that it is a named parameter. Using a - is a pretty standard indicator for named parameters, to differentiate them from unnamed primary target parameters, such as in:

```
Add-Migration initial
```

Where `initial` is an unnamed primary parameter.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the keywords with the hyphen in the middle are method calls, and the other ones are the variables being passed into that method. I assume they did this to make it feel distinct, and to differentiate between the two. Much like methods typically start with a capital letter and variables start with a lower case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I accepted the other one because he elaborated more, but your answer was helpful as well, ty.

Comment: No problem, and I agree. Very well stated.

Answer (score 1):

Because the Entity Framework commands are PowerShell Cmdlets, they have been written to (for the most part) adhere to the [PowerShell Cmdlet Development Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Cmdlets commands are written using the `Verb-Noun` pattern (See the [Approved Verbs List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), and the parameter specification patterns (`-Noun [Value]`) are handled by PowerShell.

Comment: "Cmdlets commands are written using the Verb-Noun pattern (See the Approved Verbs List), and the parameter specification patterns (-Noun [Value]) are handled by PowerShell." This line was very helpful clarification/elaboration, ty.